# Arduino Systematic Flow control

Tags: arduino, process, arduino-ide, flow-control

I'm trying to get arduino uno to sequentially extract liquid from each of four chambers to a main chamber using solenoid vales, flowmeter, level sensors, and a centrifugal pump. process being open main tank solenoid valve, open valve one, extract quantity one, close valve two, delay 1 second, open valve two....

Does anyone know the best way to go about programming this? I have no coding experience outside of mathematic analysis. Trying to get it directly in the Arduino IDE. I'm also at the same time checking liquid levels and controlling temperature.

Comment: This is not a survey site or a systems-design roundtable.  Your project is far too ambitious for a first project, and your question far too broad.

Answer (score 0):

You should do one step at a time. Your project is pretty ambitious as a first project.

I would suggest going first for some small examples like letting a LED blink, using a button etc. to get a feeling for the IDE and C syntax.

When you feel confident enough with basic programs you can progress. I'd suggest to go one sensor/actuator at a time. Trying to communicate with it and verifying the data.

But keep in mind this won't be just a coding project but there will be a substantial mechanical/electrical part. Especially when dealing with liquids there are a ton of different hose diameters, voltage levels, etc.

You have to work out how to power the pump and valves safely, because the Arduino board can't handle greater currents.

If you really want to go into this project, you surely can. But keep in mind that this won't happen in a week. To get this working properly you probably will have to invest months and educate yourself not only on the programming side, but also on the electrical side.